# Parsing JSON file using JSONKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, file, parsing

I am constructing a tuning fork app. The fork should allow up to 12 preset pitches.

Moreover, I wish to allow the user to choose a theme.   Each theme will load a set of presets (not necessary to use all of them).

My configuration file would look something like this*:

---

```
theme: "A3"
comment: "An octave below concert pitch (ie A4 440Hz)"
presets: {
    A3 220Hz=220.0
}

// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_tuning
theme: "Guitar Standard Tuning"
comment:"EADGBE using 12-TET tuning"
presets: {
    E2=82.41
    A2=110.00
    D3=146.83
    G3=196.00
    B3=246.94
    E4=329.63
}

theme: "Bass Guitar Standard Tuning"
comment: "EADG using 12-TET tuning"
presets: {
    E1=41.204
    A2=55.000
    D3=73.416
    G3=97.999
}
```

---

...which need to be extracted into some structure like this:

---

```
@class Preset
{
    NSString* label;
    double freq;
}

@class Theme
{
    NSString* label;
    NSMutableArray* presets;
}

NSMutableArray* themes;
```

---

How do I write my file using JSON?  ( I would like to create a minimum of typing on the part of the user -- how succinct can I get it?  Could someone give me an example for the first theme? )

And how do I parse it into the structures using https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit?

Comment: The JSON example is malformed

Comment: Read the question more carefully (second to last paragraph).  I have never written JSON, I didn't even know about it until an hour ago.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were looking for the Objective-C code (importing the parsed object into your Objective-C-structure)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. But not having used JSON, I don't know how to write the initial file.   so it is a double barrelled question...  how to write the file and THEN how to copy it into ObjC structures.

Comment: PS sure I will accept the answer, but I usually leave it a few hours just because it changes status in SO's public search rankings the moment I accept it;  by leaving it open for a few hours I sometimes get valuable feedback from other members of the community in this time window.

Comment: Use jsonlint.com for validating your json.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a [valid](http://jsonlint.com/) JSON example based on your thoughts:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Guitar Standard Tuning",
        "comment": "EADGBE using 12-TET tuning",
        "presets": {
            "E2": "82.41",
            "A2": "110.00",
            "D3": "146.83",
            "G3": "196.00",
            "B3": "246.94",
            "E4": "329.63"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Bass Guitar Standard Tuning",
        "comment": "EADG using 12-TET tuning",
        "presets": {
            "E1": "41.204",
            "A1": "55.000",
            "D2": "73.416",
            "G2": "97.999"
        }
    }
]
```

Read a file and parse using JSONKit:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc]
                             initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
NSArray* json = [decoder objectWithData:jsonData];
```

After that, you'll have to iterate over the `json` variable using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!  Is it unavoidable to use a gadzillion " marks everywhere?

Comment: There is an error in the answer:  it should be an NSArray not an NSMutableDictionary.  It is an array of dictionary objects.

Comment: @P i: Thanks, I was actually unsure but never checked

Answer (score 6):

Using the parser in your question and assuming you have Simeon's string in an NSString variable.  Here's how to parse it:

```
#import "JSONKit.h"


id parsedJSON = [myJSONString objectFromJSONString];
```

That will give you a hierarchy of arrays and dictionaries that you can walk to get your `Preset` and `Theme` objects.  In the above case, you would get an array with two dictionaries each with a `name`, `comment` and `presets` key.  The first two will have `NSString` values and the third (`presets`) will have a dictionary as it's value with the note name as keys and the frequencies as values (as `NSString` objects).